# How can I pull keys from a dictionary based on their value and add them to a list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I was trying [this problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/top-k-frequent-elements/) on Leetcode:

> Given an integer array nums and an integer k, return the k most
> frequent elements. You may return the answer in any order.

I made a dictionary of the elements in the list and incremented their count every time that number appeared again but I'm stuck on how to get the keys that match the highest values into the list that should be returned.

The code below is what I tried. The commented out are other variations of what I tried.
I googled possible ways to do it (the commented out sections are some approaches I found) but none of them are doing what I want, and I'm unsure what I'm doing wrong.

```
def most(nums, k):

    nums_hash = {}
    nums_list = []
    
    for number in nums:
        if number in nums_hash:
            nums_hash[number] +=1
        else:
            nums_hash[number] = 1
            
    
    for key, value in nums_hash:
        if value >= k:
            nums_list.append(key)
            
            
    
    # for v in nums_hash.values():
    #     if v > k:
    #         nums_list.append(nums_hash.keys())

    
    # for number in nums_hash:
    #     if number >= k:
    #         nums_list.append(number)
            
    return nums_list
    
print(most([1,1,1,2,2,3], k = 2))
```

The error I get is

```
ERROR!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 28, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 13, in most
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object
```

Comment: Please always provde a [mcve]. If you are getting an error, post the full error message including the stack trace

Comment: please include a description of what the code is supposed to do *in the question itself*. Questions should be self-contained

Comment: but it *sounds* like you just want to iterate over the key-value pairs in a dictionary, right?

Comment: I'm sorry, I fixed it. Yes, that's what I'm trying to do. To iterate over the keys and add the most frequent ones to a list (the k most frequent values) and return the list.

Comment: Do you mean that you are simply looking for `nums_hash.items()`?

Comment: I thought I was but it turns out I misunderstood what the problem was asking for. I read it as returning a list of the elements that appear more times than the value of k.

Comment: I think part of the confusion here came from the function/argument naming, which set you up for failure a little bit. If the problem instead gave you `def k_most_common_elements(all_elements, k):` as a starting point, that probably would have helped. Online code puzzle sights tend to have impressively bad naming (which is of course subjection, but that's just IMO) which is more math-like (precise, consise) than softeng-like (clear, approachable). I'd also recommend you try to use better names in your own code. For example, `nums_hash` might be better named `histogram`, or `number_counts`.

Comment: And just to note, different languages differ in what they call common associative data structure. "Hash" is used in Ruby, but Python uses "dictionary" (the class name is `dict`, specifically). I think the Ruby name is hella confusing, given that `hash` is also a verb ("to hash something" = "to compute the result of a hash function given something") and a _different_ noun ("the hash value" = "the result hashing something").

Comment: @Alexander I didn't know that! A video I watched once called it a hash map so I thought any Python dictionary that did what I was doing in this code would be called that, and that dictionary was just a general name for the data structure.

Comment: @mkrieger1 No, I don't think that was what I was looking for. The problem turned out to be different than I thought because I initially misunderstood what I was solving for. Sorry and thank you!

Comment: @user22248976 A "Hash Map" is the correct term for a class of data structures which use hashing to accelerate the look-up of values by keys. They're typically unordered, and requirement elements to be hashable, but are fast and memory efficient. It's one of the many possible ways of implementing an associative collection, but there are others with other trade-offs. Other examples are B-trees, which don't require elements to be hashable, and instead require them to be comparable. They're slower, but preserve the sorted order of items. "Dictionary" is more of a catch-all term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is substantially correct:

```
    for number in nums:
        if number in nums_hash:
            nums_hash[number] +=1
        else:
            nums_hash[number] = 1
```

It builds a frequency table from your input. E.g., given your sample input, you get:

```
{1: 3, 2: 2, 3: 1}
```

The problem asks for the `k` most frequent terms. That means you need to:

1. Sort the table by frequency, and then
2. Return the first `k` items

You're not doing that, when you write:

```
    for v in nums_hash.values():
        if v > k:
            nums_list.append(nums_hash.keys())
```

You are producing a list of numbers *greater than* `k`, which is not what the problem is asking for. You can use the frequency table to produce a list of numbers sorted by frequency:

```
    nums_sorted = list(reversed(sorted(nums_hash, key=lambda x: nums_hash[x])))
```

Then you just need to return the first `k` elements. Putting that all together, we get:

```
import random


def most(nums, k):
    nums_hash = {}
    nums_list = []

    for number in nums:
        nums_hash[number] = nums_hash.get(number, 0) + 1

    nums_sorted = list(reversed(sorted(nums_hash, key=lambda x: nums_hash[x])))
    print("nums_hash:", nums_hash)
    print("nums_sorted:", nums_sorted)

    return nums_sorted[:k]


numbers = random.choices(range(10), k=30)

k = 2
print("numbers:", numbers)
print(f"{k} highest:", most(numbers, k=k))
```

Using your original input, the `most` function returns:

```
[1,2]
```

Running it as written with a random range of numbers produces something like:

```
numbers: [1, 0, 3, 4, 1, 4, 0, 9, 6, 6, 1, 9, 3, 8, 9, 3, 7, 8, 9, 8, 1, 3, 9, 3, 9, 7, 1, 1, 3, 4]
nums_hash: {1: 6, 0: 2, 3: 6, 4: 3, 9: 6, 6: 2, 8: 3, 7: 2}
nums_sorted: [9, 3, 1, 8, 4, 7, 6, 0]
2 highest: [9, 3]
```

I left a bunch of `print` statements in the code so you can see what the different variables look like.

---

Note that I didn't pay any attention to algorithmic complexity while writing this (which is one of the constraints on the problem), so you may not be able to use it as written. It was meant to suggest a direction, not to be an acceptable solution.

Comment: I see! I misunderstood what the problem was asking for. Thank you both for clarifying and explaining what you did! I'm also not paying attention to the complexity as I'm not submitting it. Just practicing for myself. Would you suggest solving it without using lambda? Is there even a way to do it? I'm not 100% comfortable with it yet.

Comment: Just for reference, this histogram building can be done really conveniently with [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) https://realpython.com/python-counter/ Of course, it's better to implement these yourself as a learning exercise until you get comfortable.

Comment: @user22248976 Are you familiar with functions in general? You could define a `def sort_key(number): return nums_hash[number]`. A lambda is just a function without a name. In this case, it's used to tell `sorted` how exactly to sort the given `nums_hash`. Which for your case, is that you want to sort each item based on the value from that `nums_hash`.

Comment: @Alexander I'll keep those in mind for future reference, thank you! I really do want to get more comfortable first!

Comment: @Alexander Ok, I think that makes sense! A lambda does the same thing as a function but without a name, like in your example, sort_key.

Comment: @user22248976 I don't have much more to add here, but I just wanna say, I really love your attitude. You're open to new things, while still playing it slow to gain a solid footing. Programming can be hard to learn, but I think you're well setup for success.

Comment: @Alexander Thank you, I appreciate it! Algorithms are tough but I'm trying my best to get better at them!